# How to redirect example.com to example.com/xyz?

Tags: linux, apache, tomcat, webserver, redirect

I am using Apache 2.4.9 in RHEL 6.9.

How do I redirect a request from `example.com` to `example.com/xyz`? When I open `example.com`, it should redirect to `example.com/xyz`

How I can do that? Do I need to make changes in `httpd.conf` or any other file?
Or will it be possible by `Tomcat`?

Comment: do you try .htaccess?

Comment: I'm surprised someone upvoted this question. An upvote indicates research effort (among other things). It appears you made no effort to find the answer. The question has been asked and answered so many times you would have to make an effort to avoid an answer.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.